# VMDK disk image import failure on Google Cloud Plataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian

Dears,

I am trying to import a vmdk image disk to GCE without success. The original disk is bootable and running with Debian 8 OS.
The link to jessie packeges is broken.How can i solve it? Is it a bug from Google scripts?

This is the output Error:

> [import-image]: 2020-07-28T20:40:40.265Z step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-image-translate-disk-hwhqh": "TranslateFailed: error: sh: W: **Failed to fetch https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages HttpError404"**
> ERROR
> ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

Answer (score 0):

This is because Debian 8 "jessie" support has reached its end-of-life.
[Debian > News > Latest News > Debian 8 Long Term Support reaching end-of-life](https://www.debian.org/News/2020/20200709)

At this time

- Debian 9 “Stretch” is generally available and is supported by Debian
  LTS support,
- Debian 10 “Buster” is supported by Debian.

[Debian > Wiki > LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS)

Therefore the only `buster/` and `stretch/` subdirectories remain available at https://packages.sury.org/php/dists/.